# android web view google login

Tags: android, google-authentication

I've searched a lot for this, but not so much info found.

Actually i'm trying to implement disqus in my app, and it has google authentication, which is disallowed by google from embedded web views.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: hit this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

I didn't worked with disqus but you can use Google SingIn authorization to get some user data including id, email and other personal info inside your app. Or you can integrate Google SignIn into your backend and after verifying JWT get the same info on the server.

[Useful link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)